# sed adds string at the end of each new line

Tags: bash, sed, gnu-parallel

I am currently editing multiple CSVs to add 2 columns ORIGIN_FILE and WRITE_DATE. The problem is that the string is always added after a new line for some reason.

Here is an example of my input csv:

```
PRODUCT, QUANTITY, PRICE
ITEM1, 4.8, 380.33
ITEM2, 2.3, 120.50
ITEM3, 1.5, 210.11
```

But everytime I run my bash command below:

```bash
find $target_dir -type f -name "*.csv" | parallel sed -i '\'1s/$/,ORIGIN_FILE,WRITE_DATE/; 2,$s/$/,myfilename.csv,2022-11-24/\'' {}'
```

This is the output I get:

```
PRODUCT, QUANTITY, PRICE, ORIGIN_FILE, WRITE_DATE
ITEM1, 4.8, 380.33
myfilename.csv, 2022-11-24
ITEM2, 2.3, 120.50
myfilename.csv, 2022-11-24
ITEM3, 1.5, 210.11
myfilename.csv, 2022-11-24
```

It always creates a new line after the second row and add my string there.

I'm hoping to get this output:

```
PRODUCT, QUANTITY, PRICE, ORIGIN_FILE, WRITE_DATE
ITEM1, 4.8, 380.33, myfilename.csv, 2022-11-24
ITEM2, 2.3, 120.50, myfilename.csv, 2022-11-24
ITEM3, 1.5, 210.11, myfilename.csv, 2022-11-24
```

Hoping someone can help me spot what I'm doing wrong.

I'll appreciate if someone can just help me with the sed command.

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you test the command on one file: `sed  '1s/$/,ORIGIN_FILE,WRITE_DATE/; 2,$s/$/,myfilename.csv,2022-11-24/' input.csv`?

Comment: When I run your command, I get: `bash: 2,/$/,myfilename.csv,2022-11-24/' {}: No such file or directory`, and it doesn't modify the CSV - no newlines, no extra text.

Comment: It works fine for me if I do: `find . -type f -name "*.csv" -exec sed -i '1s/$/, ORIGIN_FILE, WRITE_DATE/; 2,$s/$/, myfilename.csv, 2022-11-24/' {} \;`.  The `{}` can be used inside a `-exec` option of the `find` command, not outside of it (i.e. after a pipe `|`).

Comment: @WalterA , I tried your suggested command to edit 1 csv file. But I'm still getting the same output. I really don't understand why it's happening.

Comment: I'm trying this `2,$s/\n/,myfilename.csv,2022-11-24\n/` but this doesn't seem to work either. It won't add anything at the end of each line.

Comment: @Nic3500, I also tried your solution and it still add the strings after newline. Hmmm, I don't see anything weird about my csv file aside from "it's huge". It contains around 2500 columns.

Comment: Make sure your csv file has linux format end of lines.  `dos2unix blabla.csv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem using the command below:

```bash
sed  '1s/$/,ORIGIN_FILE,WRITE_DATE/; 2,$s/\(\s\)\?$/,myfile.csv,2022-11-24/gmi' myfile.csv
```

I had to add
`\(\s\)\?$` in the matching regex because it looks like my input file is having an invisible whitespace which is not a `\n` character but it pushes my data down to the next line. The reason I know that it is not `\n` because I cannot match it in the regex using `\n$`.

I'm still puzzled on what's happening here. But I'm really glad I was able to solve it with all your help and suggestions.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute find with `-exec`:

```bash
find . -type f -name "*.cvs" -exec sed -i '1s/$/, ORIGIN_FILE, WRITE_DATE/; 2,$s/$/, myfilename.csv, 2022-11-24/' {} \;
```

Comment: I tried to run it, and nothing happens. Command finishes after .3 seconds

Comment: `find /dbfs/mnt/ukmotortest/POLICY/SOLDQUOTES/ -type f -name "*.cvs" -exec sed -i '1s/$/,ORIGIN_FILE,WRITE_DATE/; 2,$s/$/,LANDSCAPEPOLICIESFULL_Snowflake.csv,2022-11-25/' {} \;`

Comment: Is it possible if a send you a copy of my csv file? Ill chunk it out and give you atleast 25-50 mb copy.